# How to create same Width and Height for card in <v-flex auto>

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to arrange the card which all the card must be equal size.

Here the example I have done: https://codepen.io/creativiousa/pen/BErpPb

I have try to change my code to `<v-card height='100%'> </v-card>`  but still not view as expected.

https://codepen.io/creativiousa/pen/BErpPb here the code that I have done.

```
<v-flex auto v-for="n in 12"
              :key="n">
```

The result must be like this: [Image Sample That I Want It To Be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecokx.png)
the card must be the same height and width as the previous card.

Comment: if anyone knows how to set a fixed size of a card or how to make all the card the same size please help for my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add  `class="px-0"` . I think it will work for you. Hope it will help.

```
<v-flex auto class="px-0" v-for="n in 12"
              :key="n">
```

Please check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPmvyO) link

Please refer more for [vutify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid) layout details.

Thanks

Comment: <v-flex auto class="px-0" v-for="n in 8" :key="n"> when i change it to 8 item it still not in the good arrangement.